# Branch from a DEV branch or branch from trunk?

Tags: svn, version-control

Back ground:

We are working out how we will control our SVN repository.  We are trying to workout a system that works in our daily business process.

Our business is based around:
  - T-SQL script files
  - An in house scripting language
  - business and form data loaded via .csv files
  - We DO NOT "compile" code.

We have 4 developers that receive work orders to make changes to SQL or components commands, data load scripts, etc.  The developer will then make a work order branch to holds their changes from either Trunk (clean production scripts) or a DEV branch (represents our DEV environment for the combined changes for all work orders), this is yet to be decided.

Our initial repository plan is something like:

Dev Branch (with all our recent changes)
Stage Branch (where we merge the work orders that are about to go to production)
Trunk (a pristine representation of production)

We often have several work orders ongoing at the same time. So we would have several active branches. It is somewhat common for the same file to be changed in multiple work orders at the same time.

This makes things complicated for tracking the work order changes that get postponed while waiting for user approval.  Sometimes they are rejected and never go in!  We risk unintentionally promoting code from these postponed work orders if we branch from DEV.

The following example illustrates the concern from branching from DEV:

- day X

  - 1    WO1 branch - gets file version 1 (from DEV)
  - 2    WO2 branch - gets file version 1 (from DEV)
  - 3    WO2 merge back to DEV - file version 2
  - 4    WO3 branch - gets file version 2 (from DEV)
  - 5    WO1 merge back to DEV - file version 3
  - 6    WO3 merge back to DEV - file version 4

Now we get approval to promote WO1 & WO3.  WO2 is lagging behind but we **must** move the others into production.

Here is the glitch.  How do I identify that WO3 has WO2 changes?  The DIF will show changes but that is to be expected.  We **cannot** install anything from WO2 as it would break our auditing requirements.

Ideally we need to extract out the WO2 changes rework WO3.  Compounding the issue WO2 may need to be reworked depending on how long it lingers as well, I.E. later work orders change the file too.  Unfortunately we will have this issue with any work order using this file as long as WO2 remains outstanding.

On the other side of the coin, If we branch from trunk we have some issues as well.

- We are missing all the changes from other recent work orders using the same file(s). 
  So depending on how many changes have happen while we developed the work orders 
  independently or the changes while we wait to promote a work order could result 
  in some serious merging issues.  Hypothetically, we could reduce that risk if we got
  the branch from DEV which has the most recent changes that are merged to DEV.
- Similarly the developers need to keep their databases and environments up to date as 
  possible. But if we are pulling from trunk it may not have database schema changes 
  made in ongoing work orders. Or dependent T-SQL scripts from ongoing work orders.

Basically we are debating the benefits or costs of branching our work order changes from trunk (production) or DEV (a repository of production plus recent development changes.)

With the above info in mid does anyone have any advice for which way to go?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lazy Badger.  I see your point about our “trunk” being a “camouflaged” tag.    We could simply store the tags and get rid of what I was calling “trunk” completely.   We will most likely be doing that.  From this point on I will call the “main line” trunk.
I believe I follow your bulleted suggestions.  However, I have a few issues that I would need to resolve…   Particularly in regards to bullet 2, 3, merging and our version/install requirements.

Comment: I have to install the exact version number of the SVN files that we used in our validation testing.  Since I might have the same file in two work orders I will need to merge them and then move that merged file and the exact version of that merged file into production.    
I have been thinking about how to accomplish this and I have come up with the following as a possibility.

Comment: I need to merge the work order files somewhere and I need to make sure I use the same version of the file used in validation into production.  So I could merge the work orders into trunk (yes I know this breaks the bullet number 3).   This would mean the version in trunk will be the version that we test and the version that goes into production.  I can then use a “dif” between the last tag and trunk to identify the files that need to be copied to validation (test) and production.

Comment: Essentially then, trunk is pure except during the time that I have the work orders being validated.  If the validation works then we will move the file into prod.  We will take another tag post install so that the tag reflects the change is in production and trunk is pure again.  If the validation fails then the offending work order will be fixed or removed and validation will continue.   Finally resulting in a new tag once validation is completed.

Comment: Now this brings me to the branch issue in bullet 2.  If I have people branch from trunk it may not be pure if I am in the middle of a validation period.  To work around this we could make our branches from tag instead.  This means the developers will not accidently grab code that is in a work order being validated.  
The drawback to this is that the developer will be working in isolation from everyone else’s code and even their own code if it is being validated.   However, If we don’t work in isolation we risk introducing

Comment: unapproved code.  If we work in isolation we risk making code that will not work with other code introduced during our development.   
We can mitigate this issue slightly by doing the synch you mentioned in bullet 4 so we will do this.  I say slightly because the synch will not happen till the code changes are approved.  By that point the isolated developer may be WAY off track of the main line.  Merging the code could potentially be impossible.

Comment: What do you think? DO you see major flaws in this process?  I realize it does not exactly follow all the bullets but it seems the best way that I should think of to solve my version install requirement.  
My major concern at the moment is how I get the branch from tag to be associated with the trunk and not the tag so that when we merge them into trunk the logs make sense.   I think I can branch tag then merge trunk but have no idea how crazy that will seem in the log or following the versioning of the files in “history”.

Comment: I realize this reveals my naivety of SVN but maybe there is a way to branch from tag but re associate the branch as if it was from trunk???  There is a similar thread out here and it has some good points but seemed to peter out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906218/branching-from-a-tag

Answer (score 1):

1. You are victim of premature merges
2. You have seriously re-think about using BASE-branches: overlapping functionality, **Trunk is** slightly camouflaged **tags**...

   - Use single branch as real "mainline", which doesn't have other changesets, than mergesets from "WorkOrders" branches
   - Always create WO-branches from HEAD of "mainline"
   - Never merge unapproved WO-branches to mainline
   - Perform sync-merges from mainline to WIP WO-branches, if mainline changed during time of branch's lifetime